# Split a multidimensional numpy array using a condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional `numpy` array.
The first array indicates the quality of the data. 0 is good, 1 is not so good.
For a first check I only want to use good data.
How do I split the array into two new ones?
My own idea does not work:

```
good_data = [x for x in data[0,:] if x = 1.0]
bad_data = [x for x in data[0,:] if x = 0.0]
```

Here is a small example indicating my problem:

```
import numpy as np

flag = np.array([0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
temp = np.array([300., 310., 320., 300., 222., 333.])
pressure = np.array([1013., 1013., 1013., 900., 900., 900.])
data = np.array([flag, temp, pressure])

good_data = data[0,:][data[0,:] == 1.0]
bad_data  = data[0,:][data[0,:] == 0.0]

print good_data
```

The print statement gives me `[1., 1., 1.]`.

But I am looking for `[[1., 1., 1.], [300., 222., 333.], [900., 900., 900.]]`.

Comment: OK, see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
good_data = data[0,:][data[0,:] == 1.0]
bad_data  = data[0,:][data[0,:] == 0.0]
```

This returns a `numpy.array`.

Alternatively, you can do as you suggested, but convert the resulting list to `numpy.array`:

```
good_data = np.array([x for x in data[0,:] if x == 1.0])
```

Notice the comparison operator `==` in place of the assignment operator `=`.

For your particular example, subset data using `flag == 1` while iterating over the first index:

```
good_data = [data[n,:][flag == 1] for n in range(data.shape[0])]
```

If you really want the elements of `good_data` to be lists, convert inside the comprehension:

```
good_data = [data[n,:][flag == 1].tolist() for n in range(data.shape[0])]
```

Thanks to Jaime who pointed out that the easy way to do this is:

```
good_data = data[:, data[0] == 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it is not really what I was looking for. I will try to specify my question, please see above.

Comment: That's the idea, but you are overcomplicating things, it's actually `data[:, data[0] == 1]` and `data[:, data[0] == 0]` that the OP needs.